# Not a valid ProtoBuf in JobTrackerWatcher.findJobTrackerAddr(): Retrying to connect ZooKeeper Attempt# 0 Current ZooKeeper Server:

Tags: hadoop, elastic-map-reduce, mapr

I'm getting below errors while trying to run `mapreduce` program from eclipse using `MAPR` windows client ..

Can you please help what's wrong in this .
Note : I'm able to access the MAPR fs  from window cmd prompt:

**error log like below:**

```
INFO fs.JobTrackerWatcher: Not a valid ProtoBuf in JobTrackerWatcher.findJobTrackerAddr(): c0048ds441.ics.com:5181,c0048ds4s41.ics.com:5181,c0048dss441.ics.com:5181,

    14/12/05 12:26:05 INFO fs.JobTrackerWatcher: Retrying to connect ZooKeeper Attempt# 0 Current ZooKeeper Server: c0048ds441.ics.com:5181,c0048ds4s41.ics.com:5181,c0048dss441.ics.com:5181,
```

Comment: check `jps` shows all hadoop daemons after you start.seems like a problem with `JobTracker` address issue.

Comment: Hi Thanks Mr.Chowdary ,   It's showing all daemons are running correctly .. [mapr@c0048443 ~]$ jps
18287
10986 WardenMain
3166 Jps
1147 JobTracker
3699 TaskTracker
21069
15564
6701
2992 RunJar
11575 QuorumPeerMain